# Sending data using Jquery Iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I want to send large amounts of data to and from 2 domains (e.g. Cross Domains) I was told the best way to do this is to use IFrames. My question is...

How do I go about doing this.

Is this what google does ???

Is this the best practice???

How can I better learn about this stuff.

Comment: With iframe you're going to have a security problem for cross-domain. if you are sending a lot of information you can use other methods such as SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/). As andres notes above, security is an issue-- once you get connectivity working, you'll need to think carefully about how you'll prevent malicious use of one end of the cross-domain interaction.